# Error: Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm having this problem with Laravel:

Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?)

[image]

I tried to solve this error by enabling extension in php.ini
from this `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll` to this `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

Comment: Production or dev?

Comment: what happens when you run `phpinfo()`? Does it actually show that the fileinfo exntension is actually enabled? If not, it might not actually be installed.

Comment: Please, try to not post code as an image.